# PHP redirect loop issue

Tags: php, pdo

When I submit my category search form, I want it to run the php code in the DisplayMealsCont.php and then go back to the main.php with the updated session variables. But when I try to put in a Header("Location: ../View/Main.php"); in the DisplayMealsCont.php it gets stuck in a redirect loop.

main.php

```
<?php 
require_once("../Controller/DisplayMealsCont.php");
session_start();


$category = "All";
if(isset($_SESSION['table'])){
    $table = $_SESSION['table'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['Category'])){
    $category = $_SESSION['Category'];
    if($category == "All"){
    $category = " ";
    }
} 
?>
<?php 

if (is_array($table)) {
foreach($table as $item) { 
?>

 <td align="centre"> <?= $item['Meal_Name'] ?> </td>
    <td align="centre"> <?= $item['Description'] ?> </td>
    <td align="centre"> <?= $item['Image'] ?> </td>
    <td align="centre"> <?= $item['Category'] ?> </td>
    <td align="centre"> <?= $item['Quantity'] ?> </td>
    <td align="centre"> &pound; <?= $item['Price'] ?> </td>
   <tr> 

 <?php
 }
 }

 ?>
</table>

    <form method="post" action="../Controller/DisplayMealsCont.php">
        Category: <br />
        <select name="Category">
        <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Main">Main</option>
            <option value="Drink">Drinks</option>
        </select> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" name="categorysubmit" value="Search" />
        </form>
```

DisplayMealModel.php

```
<?php
require_once("../Model/config.php");

class DisplayMeals 
{
public $dbConnection;

public function __construct(){

    $db= new database();
    $connect=$db->getdatabase();
    $this->dbConnection = $connect;

}

public function MainMeals($category){  
    $_SESSION['test'] = $category;
    $stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from meal WHERE Category LIKE '$category%'");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



}
?>
```

DisplayMealCont.php

```
<?php
require("../Model/DisplayMealModel.php");


$newMeal = new DisplayMeals();
if(!isset($category)){
$category = "main";
}
if(isset($_SESSION['Category'])){
$category = $_SESSION['Category'];
}
$table = $newMeal-> MainMeals($category);
$_SESSION['table'] = $table;



?>
```

Comment: It means that the target-page has another redirect, which has another redirect...

Comment: can you show me where i redirect because i've only known how to redirect using headers. thank you

Comment: Depends where you put it, but keep in mind that you include that file in your main, so that it will always redirect to itself.

Comment: i thank you so much, you've fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why a header() in there causes a redirection loop, but have you tried adding a die(); after header()?

It's a good practice, and in case it works it may shed light into what is causing the issue. Other than that, it would help if you posted the code with the looping header in it so we can see.

Comment: yes, i've tried die(); and exit(); after the header and i still get the same issue

Comment: How do you know it is a redirection issue? What error do you get? You can set a session variable on DisplayMealCont.php, and on the main page die() with a display message if that session variable is found, to see if the header is in fact working. Header may not be working because of the "headers have already been sent"  error message, which depending on your server configuration may not be shown

Comment: when i open the main.php on my browser, i get "This webpage has a redirect loop" error

Comment: Wait, I just realized the "require_once("../Controller/DisplayMealsCont.php");" on main.php.  Given that displayMealsCont.php is a file without a class structure, it will execute everything in it once you require won't it? That is what is causing the redirection loop. Main should loop even when you don't submit the form and access it directly